# How to merge arrays from different input values.?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter-3

There are many text field with same name and same class with different values and each input have 1 button.  I get the value from each one of the fields by clicking on each specific button. Using with Javascript. And i can put that value into array but the arrays are not merge. If i click on 1st button the specific input field value is put into the array, then i click on 3rd button the 1st value in array is removed and the new vlaue (3rd row's value) is stored in array. How can i store all of the values in same array on each click button.

Here is my code.

```
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="aaa"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="bbb"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="ccc"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="ddd"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="eee"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
</div>
```

Here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Get the value on button click
    var div = $(this).closest('div');
    var get_eupdid = div.find('input').val();

    alert(get_eupdid);

    //Push the value into array.
    var array_id = [];

    array_id.push(get_eupdid);

    console.log( "array_id: " + array_id);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this** :Click function not there  and declare the `array` as a global

```js
var array_id = [];
$('.clickme').click(function(){
   var get_eupdid= $(this).closest('div').find('input').val();
   array_id.push(get_eupdid);
   console.log( "array_id: " + array_id);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="aaa"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="bbb"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="ccc"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="ddd"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
</div>

<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="myvalue" class="form-control input_text" value="eee"/>
    <input type="button" class="clickme" value="Get Value" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check this out. There's usually no need for `<input type='hidden' />` when you can use something else to store the data. Also, it shows you how, with a little bit of CSS, unless you'd like to put something else in those `<div>`s, how you can do that.

```js
$(function(){

 var possible = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee'], collection = [];
 $('.clickme').each(function(i, e){
    $(e).click(function(){
      collection.push(possible[i]);
      console.log(collection);
    });
 });

 });
```

```css
.clickme{
  display:block;
 }
```

```html
<head>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <input type='button' class='clickme' value='Get Value' />
    <input type='button' class='clickme' value='Get Value' />
    <input type='button' class='clickme' value='Get Value' />
    <input type='button' class='clickme' value='Get Value' />
    <input type='button' class='clickme' value='Get Value' />
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make array global.Right now you are creating `array` every time a `button` is clicked so only `current value` remain in `array`

```
 var array_id = [];
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $(".clickme").click(function () {
     var div = $(this).closest('div');
     var get_eupdid = div.find('input').val();
     alert(get_eupdid);

     //Push the value into array.
      array_id.push(get_eupdid);

      console.log("array_id: " + array_id);
    });
});
```